# How to extract MDX or SQL query from excel pivot table

Tags: sql, excel, pivot-table, mdx, olap

I have an excel file reading some data from an OLAP service. The query was constructed using the GUI. How can I obtain the corresponding MDX or SQL query that excel actually communicates to the OLAP server?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through SQL server profiler. Just run the profiler on Analysis Services and run/refresh your query in Excel and you will see the MDX query in the profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your pivot table -> Tools -> Show Mdx

Answer (score 0):

you can use this vba

```
Sub CheckMDX()
 
 Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
 
 Set pvtTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
 
 Debug.Print pvtTable.MDX
 
End Sub
```